# SVG Filter animation with transition when mouse over and leave

Tags: javascript, svg, filter, svg-animate

I want to apply an SVG filter with a transition. I want it to be applied when the mouse is on it and discarded when the mouse left it. I've tried this code but it didn't work. How can I do that?

```js
var rect = document.querySelector("rect")
var use = document.querySelector("#fs")

rect.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  rect.setAttribute("filter","url(#filter)")
  use.setAttribute("href","startA")
})

rect.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  rect.setAttribute("filter","")
  use.setAttribute("href","stopA")
})
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <animate id="startA" attributeName="stdDeviation" values="0;10" dur="1s"></animate>
    <animate id="stopA" attributeName="stdDeviation" values="10;0" dur="1s"></animate>
  </defs>
  <filter id="filter">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10">
      <use id="fs"/>
    </feGaussianBlur>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="180" height="180" fill="#4a8"></rect>  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to mix SMIL and javascript when you can do the whole thing in SMIL.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <filter id="filter">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0">
    <animate begin="r.mouseover" attributeName="stdDeviation" values="0;10" dur="1s" fill="freeze"></animate>
    <animate begin="r.mouseout" attributeName="stdDeviation" values="10;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze"></animate>
    </feGaussianBlur>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  
  <rect id="r" x="50" y="50" width="180" height="180" fill="#4a8" filter="url(#filter)"></rect>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question. If I  have more rects, how can I do that?

Comment: Multiple filters.

Comment: Actually, here is my problem. I wrote a script that creates a chart with respect to the numbers entered. So, SVG elements on which the filter is applied are being created with Javascript. In javascript, creating all filter elements one by one means lots of code. Is there a shortcut for this I can use?  I've tried to add the filter and the begin attributes with mouseover event but it didn't work.

Comment: create the filters with javascript too.